# How to copy wallet.dat from v0.10.2.0 to v0.11.0.

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core

I am trying to import the balance from the older version to the newer one. I deleted the wallet.dat from the newer one and copied the older one into its place. However, the wallet will not start with the old wallet.dat. I get a small "error" msg box. When I click "ok" qt closes down.

Are the two wallets incompatible? If so, is there another way to import my balance to the new wallet?

Thanks

Comment: What does the error message box say?

Comment: Its a very small box that says "Bitcoin" in the title bar, then it has a red circle with a white x in the box with an "ok button underneath. When I click the "ok" button, qt shuts down. If I do nothing, qt freezes (behind the box) with "verifying wallet..." printed at the bottom.

Comment: Now I tried to importwallet from the console but got the following error: Cannot open wallet dump file (code -8)

Comment: The strange thing is that this wallet.dat that I can not open in another instance of qt, works just fine in the original qt client it came from.

Answer (score 1):

As there was no response for this, and in case someone else has the same problem, I dumped the private keys, and then imported them to the other client.